Multiple I2C GPIO Expander give probing error due to shared reset pin
I'm editing the kernel device tree for a custom board. I have two GPIO expanders (pcal6416) connected to i2c3 bus. The two expanders share the same CPU pin as reset. Here is the initial device tree
&i2c3 {
    clock-frequency = <400000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default", "gpio";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c3>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&pinctrl_i2c3_gpio>;
    scl-gpios = <&gpio5 18 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    sda-gpios = <&gpio5 19 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    status = "okay";

    /* GPIO expander */
    exp_gpio0: exp_gpio0@20 {
        compatible = "nxp,pcal6416";
        reg = <0x20>;
        gpio-controller;
        reset-gpios = <&gpio1 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        wakeup-source;
        status = "okay";
    };
    
    exp_gpio1: exp_gpio1@21 {
        compatible = "nxp,pcal6416";
        reg = <0x21>;
        gpio-controller;
        reset-gpios = <&gpio1 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};

With this, I get a probing error on boot on the second device
pca953x: probe of 2-0021 failed with error -16

If I run i2cdetect on the i2c bus I get this
root@imx8mp-var-dart:~# i2cdetect -y 2
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: UU 21 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --           

I can also add the device manually with echo exp_gpio1 0x20 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_device (but I don't get the relative gpiochip). So, the expander is up and running. But can't be probed on boot.
If I disable the first expander, the second gets probed correctly on boot.
Via trial and error, I discovered that removing the reset-gpios option on the second expander, everything gets loaded correctly on boot.
My guess is that the kernel probes for the first expander and finds it, than plays with the reset pin. Then it probes for the second, but it is still in reset state, and don't get probed correctly.
So, what's the best thing to do to deal with this condition?
I see these options:

use a different GPIO to control the 2 expanders' resets. This needs a reworking of the board electronics. Quite expensive
leave as is, with one expander with reset defined and the other without reset. It works, but I don't really like it...
tweak the kernel source code to deal with this. Any idea where to look at?
remove the reset gpio from both expanders' nodes and define a GPIO, fixed in non-reset state. Will probably work (if controlled before probing; better to add to u-boot device tree, too), but of course I lose the reset. Although I doubt I will actually use it
other options?

